# reactjs - Как прибавить значение в input

Tags: reactjs

Как мне прибавить значение value в input, что бы не просто заменить его на другое, а + к предыдущему

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function KeyBoard() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    const clickBtn = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let value = e.target.value;
        changeInput(value);
    };

    const changeInput = (value) => {
        setInputValue(value);
    };
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value={inputValue} />
            <button value="1" onClick={clickBtn}>
                1
            </button>
            <button value="2" onClick={clickBtn}>
                2
            </button>
            <button value="3" onClick={clickBtn}>
                3
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default KeyBoard;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const changeInput = (value) => {
        setInputValue(inputValue + value);
    };
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]